# python: query mongodb database to find nearest neighbors of a coordinate?

Tags: python, mongodb, nearest-neighbor

I am using mongodb (version 2.6) and all my coordinate data is saved as GeoJSON format. Now I want to query the database to find 10 nearest neighbors of a specific coordinate.

I want to use $near defined in mongodb, however, I notice this only returns nearest neighbors in a region specified by minDistance and maxDistance, i.e, the number of nearest neighbors may not be the same for different coordinates. However, I just want to get 10 nearest neighbors for each point, anyone knows good method to do that?

Comment: [limit?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Put maxDistance to a very large value e.g. 20000*1000 metres, that increases your scope to full Earth.

http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzcircumference.htm

2. Now use $near operator , with $limit = 10.
   you will get 10 nearest neighbours irrespective of how far they are located.

> the_collection.find({'loc_field': {'$near': {'$maxDistance':> 20000*1000,
>   '$geometry': geometry_of_the_coordinate}}).limit(10)

Comment: Pathak  sounds cool, by the way, it should be 20000*1000 instead of 10000, right

Comment: Yes. my mistakes with the zero, it should be 20 thousand kilometers * 1000 to convert it to meters

Comment: oh and by the way, limit(10) should be put in the end, right? otherwise there is unbalanced bracket

Comment: Is limit() only valid for mongodb version >3.0? It doesn't work in my case and returns all data back  ><